How do you respond to students complaining that practice questions are both insufficient and too easy?
Having been teaching at the undergraduate level for six years, I have always been receiving complaints from students about:

The practice questions I gave are too easy and do not match the difficulty level of the actual test.
There should be more practice questions.
I attended all classes and understood EVERYTHING. But I could not do the actual test questions. I simply don't know what to do.

What are appropriate responses to these?

from your viewpoint, would you say the difficulty level for practice and actual test questions differs (and thus the students actually have a point) or not?

Well, are these complaints true? I'm not sure how we can help you responding to these questions, we don't know if your test questions match the practice questions and your learning content.

In my experience, most undergrads don't know how to use practice questions properly; they just flip directly to the solution and try to memorize it. But that won't be enough even to solve closely related questions of the same difficulty.

When I was a student I used practice problems as a way to judge my competency. If the questions were too easy, I’d develop a false confidence in my ability.

What are you looking for? A way to tell your students you think they are wrong (i.e. your practice questions are enough and not too easy)? A way to tell your students you don't care (i.e. the question are easier than on the exam, but you are not going to change that)? Or a way to adjust your practice questions and/or exam questions so you don't get those complaints in the future?

A way to have them understand that practice questions are only meant to cover SOME topics that will be covered in the test, and that these practice questions are at the easier side (meaning that in the actual test, I'd like to see if you TRULY understand and are able to apply the learned concepts). Suggestions?

@user2574706 To help your students develop that true understanding, perhaps you should give them harder practice questions, that cover all the topics.

@user2574706 I think your approach is wrong - practice makes perfection, not theoretical studies of the material. At the very least, make it clear to your students THROUGHOUT THE COURSE that these questions are not representative for the exam questions so they can try to find practice questions themselves. Right now, I'd say your students are right in complaining, so there's nothing I can suggest you tell them.

It would be helpful if you could edit the question to add: (1) whether you agree with the assessment of the students; (2) what you have already tried; (3) specifics such as where you get the practice questions and where you get the exams.  For example, when I was in college many years ago, it was common (at least within the basic sciences) to use exams from previous years as practice exams; and (4) what your colleagues have to say about the issue. Do they also get similar complaints?

Based on your comment, it sounds like you are intentionally making the test harder than any of the practice problems and perhaps requiring that students can do things on the test that have not been spelled out in the lecture? If so, how can you expect anyone to be able to succeed on tests unless they know the material from outside of your class? How could they be prepared to "TRULY understand" if they have no way to discover that there are gaps in their understanding? Are they supposed to have psychic powers to learn what they need to know?

How about giving past examinations?

Make sure the practice questions are harder by at least 2 to 3 notches than the exam. You do have time during practice, people and tutors to discuss with, and no pressure.
All of which you do not have in the exam.
There can be one difficult question in the exam (as Buffy suggests), but it should be clearly marked and should only be enough to distinguish the top layer of the students, but not be pass-critical or relevant lower to middling grades.

As a wise professor once said: if you simply ask students to regurgitate what you told them, this will already allow you to distinguish the students who have learned the material from those who haven't. Maybe you want to add one hard question to challenge the best students and motivate people to study harder, but that's enough.

@user1149748: But I don't really care if the students have learned the material.  I really only care if students have learned to think and communicate.  The material is merely an exercise machine to train on.

I disagree that practicals should be harder. Sure, you have more time and people to discuss with, but practicing should allow one to solve similar questions on your own and in shorter time in the future, e.g. in an exam. And I've seen enough people who, by only practicing harder tasks, failed the simple task in an exam when trying to apply the tools needed for the harder task.

@Sabine If you want to easily run 5km, train to run 10km.

@Sabine If you worry about that, shortly before the exam, tell them that the exam will be slightly easier than the practicals. Also, sometimes, the exam questions think they are hard, but aren't. As a student I encountered a question that was supposed to be very hard, but found a two-liner shortcut that nobody (not even the setter of the question) had seen. It cuts both ways.

As a practical matter you often already have these too-hard questions -- Q's that were written for the exam, but are just a little to hard (ambiguous, too much set-up, too much to write... ).

@Sabine - this means that the students did not learn how to think and communicate, only how to apply the material in situations where someone else has thought about it for them.

@ZeroTheHero That's a way to run a 5K, but it's not a good way to win a 5K. In other words, it's not clear how that analogy applies to mathematics.

@AlexanderWoo Are you expecting students to learn to "think and communicate" in only about 14 weeks (or whatever the length of a class you're teaching)? Seems like a lot to expect. If the material is just the "exercise machine", that should apply to all material. So the 12 years of school before their first undergraduate class is also about thinking? So one university class is at most 1/24 of their total education in "thinking and communicating". Seems to me if they can merely state Lagrange's Theorem on a test and remember it after graduation, that's not too shabby at all.

That's a good advice, but practice questions should not be too hard: if you make a question about a certain problem/skill too hard, they may label all the same problems as hard and skip it during exams. Ideally, there should be some progressivity in practice: an obvious question (to clear misunderstanding), then several simpler to exam-level questions to assimilate the method, and then harder to test their thinking ability. And that may not be necessary to label the harder question: that's a skill to know for which problem there is a standard method, and which one there is not.

@ToddWilcox the training should be harder than the actual event (when practical).  This isn’t about winning, it’s about finishing.  In addition assignments should be formative, where you train your brain to think about problems, whereas tests should be summative.

@Taladris There always should be a spectrum of easy-to-difficult questions in the practicals. Easy reproduction, technical skill and understanding. But the spectrum should be stretched further towards harder questions than what you assess in the exam.

Maybe you can clarify: I think exercises over the duration of the whole course should be in a range from very easy to a bit harder than the exam. And one can clearly explain "now this is the kind of questions you will see in the exam" - "if you can do these 3 questions in 20mins you can be quite confident to do well in the exam"

@Falco Personally (philosophy may vary), I am very much against telling students that something they learn will be practically equivalent to an exam. They should have a certain amount of uncertainty. Otherwise, they will learn by rote. Sometimes, this is unavoidable, but it should not be the general case. Being adaptable is part of what an exam should be assessing.

Choose one of the practice questions and put it on the test
As a math teacher, I used to get complaints from students that the tests were harder than the homework, even though that was not true.
Then I started putting one of the questions from the homework on the test. This would typically be a question that looks easy at first glance, but is actually a bit difficult. (I don't check homework, but I guess some students skip these types of questions on their homework.)
I found that usually this question was one of the lowest scoring questions on the test.
Then, when discussing the test afterwards, I would say for example "Question 6 was copied directly from the homework, but only 46% of students got it right."
Then the students stopped complaining that the tests were harder than the homework... and started paying more attention to their homework.

Overall I think this is a good idea, with some limitations. When working on homework, you can refer to the textbook and notes and take more than a class period working on a single problem. So the exact same problem could be a lot harder to solve in a test environment with limited time and no access to information not in one's head compared to the homework environment. Only if students essentially memorize the homework problems would this be always an easy question for those who have done the homework.

Consider that perhaps they are correct. You can, if you like, provide a wider range of practice questions, some quite difficult. You can also, if you like, make the tests a bit easier.
In some ways the practice set is like an advertisement for the exam, saying, in effect, "this is what the exam will be like." If that is false advertising then you should probably make changes. You can, imperfectly, solve the "advertising" problem by telling them that the exam will be harder than the practice problems, but that is unlikely to please them.
Don't make the exams a "gotcha" exercise. If the practice questions give the wrong impression about what the test will be like, you aren't actually helping the students prepare for the exam. Even dropping the practice questions might be better.
My old (retired now) practice was to put one very difficult question on each exam, but warn the students ahead of time that this would happen. That question didn't greatly affect grading, but gave the best students something to chew on.
I never tried the following and it just occurred to me. If one needs five problems for an exam, then make up ten valid questions and randomly choose half of them as practice questions. I'd need to think about this for a while and find a way to assure coverage for both the exam and the practice sets. Just a thought.

In addition to the other answers, consider that no matter what you do, there will always be people who are going to be unhappy.
Over the years, for one of my recurring larger classes I have done the following:
Gave lots of simple problems to solidify context - then asked few but composite type problems where understanding of those concepts can be demonstrated (some students complained that I was testing them on concepts they had never seen before).
Gave difficult problems to teach them the concepts and just asked very simple problems on tests so they can answer easily in a stress free manner to demonstrate that they got the basics of those concepts (some students complained that I wasted their time with problems that they were not specifically tested on).
Gave the EXACT problems to study throughout the year and then asked them again, unchanged on their final (some students complained that I asked them questions on concepts they had never seen before).
So, take that for what it's worth. Whenever I have student comments or complaints I try to take a real honest look at them to see how I may be able to improve. I'll even ask my colleagues to check whether I may be blind to something. However, my experience has been that you can't please everybody.
My approach now is to just give them a wide range and test them on a highly representative pool (they still complain, but there's only so much attention I can give to my service class given my research and mentoring FTE being over three times that of my teaching)

Since you have been teaching the same subject for six years, you have a nice collection of exams. You just need to publish those exams for your students to practice or even for you or other lecturers to use as exercises in class.
This way, nobody can complain that the practice exercises are easier/harder/different from the test exercises. Additionally, you will be using a material that has costed you work to produce.
In case you don't like the idea of publishing a collection of exams, please be sure that the students already have them - unless you have been careful to avoid students taking exams in previous years to take home the statements, and even then they may have been reconstructed from memories.


The practice questions I gave are too easy and do not match the difficulty level of the actual test.

In addition to the great advice of other answers, another option -- provided you are comfortable with this and it is allowed by policy -- would be to use questions from previous exams that you have given as test questions. That's not a guarantee that the difficulty will be equal, but difficulty is partly subjective, and at least gives you response you can use if you get complaints about difficulty.

There should be more practice questions.

As a student, I remember always wishing there were more practice problems. Seeing the other side, I understand why it's hard to generate an arbitrary number of good practice problems. One practical idea (if you have a textbook) is to say additional practice can be found by doing problems in the textbook that weren't assigned as homework. You could also suggest specific unassigned problems to do.

I attended all classes and understood EVERYTHING. But I could not do the actual test questions. I simply don't know what to do.

To some extent, there's not much you can do about this. Obviously if they understood EVERYTHING then they could do the exam (assuming the exam doesn't require the use of some technique not covered in class). It's hard to say in general whether the person saying this was anxious in the exam, or if they are exaggerating their understanding, or if the problem genuinely was more difficult than what they had seen before.
There is one situation I remember coming up as a student that might be relevant here. Sometimes, on a problem, it's possible to take a wrong turn, and suddenly the problem looks very unlike anything you've seen before. Especially at the beginning of a problem when you haven't figured out how to fit it into the framework of the class and you are staring at a white piece of paper. For example, you can make an algebra mistake and suddenly the integral you need to do is impossible, or you could think the problem looks like it needs method A when it actually needs method B, and get stuck on trying to make method A work. It can be difficult to accept that you've made a wrong turn and need to throw away some work and go back under exam pressure, partly because of time pressure and partly because of a sunk cost fallacy. It is useful to be able to say in these situations that the solution can be found using similar methods that could be used to solve practice problems and with similar amount of grunt work, and if they are hitting a wall then they might want to rethink their approach or check their work.
Another scenario that came up as a grader for a quantitative field (physics) that I found surprising was that often, students did better and it was easier to give partial credit for quantitative problems ("calculate this") compared to short response type questions ("what would happen if we did this?"). The hardest problem I ever graded -- both in terms of how the students did and in terms of how hard I found it to give partial credit -- was a purely conceptual question ("what would happen to this superconductor if I turned on a magnetic field?" etc). However, it was also very easy to see who understood the material and who didn't. Although it probably wouldn't be popular, that kind of question might be useful to give as practice (or on a test) to show that you aren't just looking for the ability to carry out an algorithm, but to reason from principles given in class. Relatedly, in intro physics, I often found that the conceptual questions in the textbook helped me understand the material much more than the calculation problems. (Later on, in upper level physics courses, the calculations become difficult enough that they are also essentially conceptual problems, so this distinction tends to disappear in upper levels, but I think it's still useful to go through detailed calculations at different levels of granularity, sometimes with a fine toothed comb to get every detail, and sometimes at an outline level to make sure all the individual steps and arguments are logically coherent).
As another strategy... I'm not sure how realistic this is since I've never seen it tried in real life, but on social media I've seen a supposed exam with the question "You probably studied topics that weren't covered on the exam, please explain one of them in detail." I could imagine something open ended like that allowing students to demonstrate knowledge and give some warm-and-fuzzy feelings toward you, as well as giving you an idea of how good their understanding is of something they think they understand well, although that might be hard to grade.
